# Force a quiet msi install despite requiring human input. using a batch file

Tags: windows-10, installation, automation, windows-installer

I have a whole set of programs that I have created a batch file to install. The problem is that seven of them are msi installers and they all require human input. However, all of the input that is required is only next, next, next, finish. There are no actual decisions that need to be made.

Is there a way of setting up the batch file commands so that these msi’s can be installed without constantly having to click on the next or finish button?

I currently have them set as:

*msiexec /i “d:\file location\myfile.msi”*

I have used Orca to look at the msi and can't make head-nor-tail of it.

Answer (score 0):

Type `msiexec /?` for help.

So `/qn` or `/quiet`.

> ```
> Windows ® Installer. V 5.0.19041.1 
>
> msiexec /Option <Required Parameter> [Optional Parameter]
>
> Install Options
>   </package | /i> <Product.msi>
>       Installs or configures a product
>   /a <Product.msi>
>       Administrative install - Installs a product on the network
>   /j<u|m> <Product.msi> [/t <Transform List>] [/g <Language ID>]
>       Advertises a product - m to all users, u to current user
>   </uninstall | /x> <Product.msi | ProductCode>
>       Uninstalls the product
> Display Options
>   /quiet
>       Quiet mode, no user interaction
>   /passive
>       Unattended mode - progress bar only
>   /q[n|b|r|f]
>       Sets user interface level
>       n - No UI
>       b - Basic UI
>       r - Reduced UI
>       f - Full UI (default)
>   /help
>       Help information
> Restart Options
>   /norestart
>       Do not restart after the installation is complete
>   /promptrestart
>       Prompts the user for restart if necessary
>   /forcerestart
>       Always restart the computer after installation
> Logging Options
>   /l[i|w|e|a|r|u|c|m|o|p|v|x|+|!|*] <LogFile>
>       i - Status messages
>       w - Nonfatal warnings
>       e - All error messages
>       a - Start-up of actions
>       r - Action-specific records
>       u - User requests
>       c - Initial UI parameters
>       m - Out-of-memory or fatal exit information
>       o - Out-of-disk-space messages
>       p - Terminal properties
>       v - Verbose output
>       x - Extra debugging information
>       + - Append to existing log file
>       ! - Flush each line to the log
>       * - Log all information, except for v and x options
>   /log <LogFile>
>       Equivalent of /l* <LogFile>
> Update Options
>   /update <Update1.msp>[;Update2.msp]
>       Applies update(s)
>   /uninstall <PatchCodeGuid>[;Update2.msp] /package <Product.msi | ProductCode>
>       Remove update(s) for a product
> Repair Options
>   /f[p|e|c|m|s|o|d|a|u|v] <Product.msi | ProductCode>
>       Repairs a product
>       p - only if file is missing
>       o - if file is missing or an older version is installed (default)
>       e - if file is missing or an equal or older version is installed
>       d - if file is missing or a different version is installed
>       c - if file is missing or checksum does not match the calculated value
>       a - forces all files to be reinstalled
>       u - all required user-specific registry entries (default)
>       m - all required computer-specific registry entries (default)
>       s - all existing shortcuts (default)
>       v - runs from source and recaches local package
> Setting Public Properties
>   [PROPERTY=PropertyValue]
>
> Consult the Windows ® Installer SDK for additional documentation on the
> command line syntax.
>
> Copyright © Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
> Portions of this software are based in part on the work of the Independent JPEG Group.
> ```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I had already looked at the msiexec /? and saw the /q switch.
The way I understand it; msiexec /q installs the msi as normal but hides it from the user. This means that when it requires human input the user neither knows about it or, if they did, would not be able to interact with the installation. Resulting in the install stalling at the first stage.
Am I correct in this?

Comment: You are not correct in a general sense. It depends on the MSIs. If you can install without interaction then `/quiet` will.  A perfect MSI will adhere to all switches, install per machine if elevated and per user if not. It should  have default folders and answers if it needs to ask anything.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a go with the /q switch and see if it works.